# How would you write the condition in ramda?

Tags: redux, functional-programming, ramda.js

I'm new to Ramda and just trying to wrap my head around it. So here is the function I want to rewrite in functional style:

```
const makeReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOG_OUT) {
    return rootReducer(undefined, action)
  }
  return rootReducer(state, action)
}
```

Here is what I end up with:

```
const isAction = type => R.compose(R.equals(type), R.prop('type'))

const makeReducer = (state, action) => {
  const isLogOut = isAction(LOG_OUT)
  return R.ifElse(isLogOut, rootReducer(undefined, action), rootReducer(state, action))(action)
}
```

I assume it's totally wrong as there are several duplications of `action` and `rootReducer`

Comment: FP doesn't mean to encode everything as functions. Using `if`/`else` conditions is just fine. You only need a functional condition if you want to partially apply it or pass it around like data.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I don't see any reason to refactor your code: you're not mutating inputs and you use `if` to conditionally return outputs.

About `rootReducer(undefined, action)`, I believe that you should use parameter destructuring:

```
const rootReducer = ({ state, action } = {}} => {
   // Stuff here
}
```

That is, you may give either `state` or `action`, or both:

```
const makeReducer = ({ state, action }) => {
  if (action.type === LOG_OUT) {
    return rootReducer({ action })
  }
  return rootReducer({ state, action })
}
```

Also, consider using terniary to solve simple cases:

```
const makeReducer = ({ state, action }) =>
     rootReducer( action.type === LOG_OUT ? { action } : { state, action } )
```

Finally, there could be yet another approach using tagged sums and folds. Since I don't work with *React* and/or *Redux*, I don't know if you could go with this approach but I believe that it's still interesting that you discover this alternative solution:

```js
const tag = Symbol ( 'tag' )

// TaggedSum
const Action = {
    logout: value => ( { [tag]: 'logout', value } ),
    login: value => ( { [tag]: 'login', value } )
}

const foldAction = matches => action => {
   const actionTag = action[ tag ]
   const match = matches [ actionTag ]
   
   return match ( action.value )
}

const state = { x: 1 }
const LOG_IN = 1
const LOG_OUT = 2
const logout = Action.logout ( { action: LOG_OUT, state } )
const login = Action.login ( { action: LOG_IN, state } )

const rootReducer = args => console.log ( args )

// Pattern matching
const matchAction = {
   logout: ( { state } ) => rootReducer( { state } ),
   login: rootReducer
}

const foldAction_ = foldAction( matchAction )

foldAction_ ( logout )
foldAction_ ( login )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the duplication fairly easily:

```
const makeReducer = (state, action) => 
  rootReducer((action.type === LOG_OUT ? undefined : state), action)
```

That is really neither more nor less functional than the original.  But it does have the advantage of reducing duplication, and of dealing only with expressions and not statements, which is sometimes a concern of functional techniques.

But there is one way in which it is clearly not functional.  There is a free variable in your code: `LOG_OUT`.  I'm guessing from the ALL_CAPS that this is meant to be a constant.  But the function doesn't know that.  So this function is not actually referentially transparent.  It's possible that between invocations with the same parameters, someone changes the value of `LOG_OUT` and you could get different results.

This makes the function harder to test.  (You can't just supply it the necessary parameters; you also have to have the correct value of `LOG_OUT` in scope.)  And it makes it much harder to reason about.

An alternative without this issue is

```
const makeReducer = (state, action, types) => 
  rootReducer((action.type === types.LOG_OUT ? undefined : state), action)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use pointfree style syntax for your code, you could do something like:

```js
const initialState = {
  text: 'initial text'
}

const rootReducer = R.curry((state, action) => {
  // setting initial state could be improved
  state = state || initialState
  // your root reducer logic here
  return state;
})

// R.last is here to grab the action in [state, action]
const isAction = type => R.compose(R.equals(type), R.prop('type'), R.last)

// first makes (state, action) into [state, action]
// before running R.cond
const makeReducer = R.compose(R.cond([
  [isAction('LOG_OUT'), R.compose(rootReducer(undefined), R.last)],
  // "default" action
  [R.T, R.apply(rootReducer)]
]), R.pair)

const loggedOutState = makeReducer(
  { text: 'latest text'},
  { type: 'LOG_OUT'}
)

console.log(loggedOutState)
// => { text: 'initial text' }

const nextState = makeReducer(
  { text: 'latest text'},
  { type: 'ANY_ACTION'}
)

console.log(nextState)
// => { text: 'latest text' }
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

What's good about this solution is that you could easily extend `makeReducer` to handle more actions (since it's using `R.cond` -- which is like a switch statement).